# Бакап таблицы (не базы) в mysql на php

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать бэкап определенной таблицы средствами PHP? Мой гугл к сожалению ищет только код [хрень](http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php) не рассчитанный на гигантские таблицы. Оч. охота решение с стандартной mysqldump, но она только базу полностью ведергивает.

Comment: Вы уж определитесь чего хотите, "Бакап таблицы ... на php" или всё-таки "решение с стандартной mysqldump".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mysqldump прекрасно поддерживает бэкапы конкретных таблиц. Первая строчка из вывода `mysqldump -?`:

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
```

Например:

```
mysqldump -u user -p database table_1 table_2 table_3 > backup.sql
```